# Deploying Azure WebJob from Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-webjobs

In Visual Studio, you can deploy a WebJob to Azure easily by right-clicking on the project and select publish. Visual Studio detects that is a Worker Service and knows that is going to be deployed in a WebJob service.
In Visual Studio Code, with Azure extension installed, you can only Deploy to Web App. Is there any way to deploy directly my project to Azure Webjob from VSCode?

Edit: Typo

Answer (score 0):

Up to now, the official only mentioned that the azure app service of windows supports webjob, and Linux does not currently support it. The official document mentions that you can use the portal website to upload webjobs, and use visual studio to publish webjobs of the .net framework (.net core programs are not supported by tools such as vs2019). Other documents about webjobs are gone.

After testing, the current use of VSCode does not support publishing Azure WebJob, you can [report issues on github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues).

Or [raise a support ticket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) to confirm with an official Microsoft engineer and get help.